# Technical problems when tracking Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

We've been tracking visitors to our site for over a year now, and when comparing last year to this year, site visitation, unique visitors, etc. have all been cut in half (roughly, not exactly half).

There isn't really a marketplace explanation for the decrease, and we're wondering if there are any technical problems we may have had to cause this to happen. We had another developer working on the site last year (who is no longer with us), and we're wondering if maybe the tracking code had been placed improperly. Our current developer looked back at the code during this time period and said that is not the issue.

Any other ideas as to why our analytics might be so off kilter?

Thanks,

Comment: Check your filters in the profile settings. Improperly set filters can destroy tracking data quickly (and irretrievably).

Answer (score 0):

Some of the reasons why this could happen are:

- Some of the pages were removed.
- Some code was removed (you say that this is not the case.)
- there was some problem specific to your site (like large number of international users etc)